# Building Boost for Android with error "cannot find -lrt"

Tags: android, c++, boost, build

So I am trying to build boost 1.55 for android, but I am getting linking errors for Boost.System and Boost.Atomic, that say "error: cannot find -lrt". Of course, android doesn't have librt because its built into the C runtime. So, I am trying to get boost so it won't link to librt. I tried just deleting every "-lrt" in the source code:

```
find . -type f | xargs -n1 -P 8 sed -i "s/-lrt//g"
```

But I still get the same error. How do I make boost not link against librt for android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed all occurrencies of `-lrt` with sed doesn't seem to have any impact on the problem.
What worked for me (in boost 1.53.0 though) is the following:

- Edit `tools/build/v2/tools/gcc.jam`
- Comment `libs = rt ;` in this code section (By the way, it could be that you do not have the `-pthread` option line):

  ```
      case * :
      {
          option = -pthread ;
          libs = rt ;   <--Comment this line
      }
  ```

---

Note: As initial/brute force solution, I would take the failed commands and manually run them removing `-lrt` from them.