# Building Boost for NDK r11 and above

Tags: boost, android-ndk

I had tried using the methods as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491158/compile-and-use-boost-for-android-ndk-r10e) but can't find a way to do so with ndk r11c. Where should I place the extracted files in the ndk-module? Can anyone help me give a step by step guide please. I am new to it and still learning :)

Comment: put your ndk files where you need, it doesn't matter, if you are going to crosscompile using android toolchain,  you will specifiy in the command line, try this references, http://www.cnx-software.com/2011/10/03/cross-compiling-boost-c-libraries-for-arm/ https://rubentorresbonet.wordpress.com/2014/08/22/cross-compiling-boost-1-56-for-android-arm-and-intel-on-windows-with-ndk-r9d-and-gcc-4-8/

Comment: neah none of them worked :(